# C# null of strings

Tags: c#, console-application

Today I need help with something I have found a error on my c# application and it is really annoying to fix, I'm very new with c# and haven't got the skill to fix it by myself the error says Unable to cast object of type `System.DBNull` to type `system.string`
Cannot proceed press any key to stop the server; it is on a file in a catch that the writeline is occuring Ive posted my full file program.cs

Here is where the catch for the try is

```
catch (Exception exception)
        {
            HandleFatalError("Could not initialize Reality: " + exception.Message);
            return;
        }
```

full program.cs file: http://chaserp.net/full.txt (if a mod can attach this) wouldn't allow me to add it?

Comment: Can you post the code that produces the exception rather than the code catching the exception? Also, please state how you want the code to behave if the database field is null. Do you expect the string to be empty? Do you expect the code to produce a more informative exception?

Answer (score 6):

Well as it says, you're trying to cast a `DBNull` to `string`. Presumably somewhere you have something like:

```
string value = (string) reader["Foo"];
```

... where the value is actually a `DBNull` (i.e. NULL in the database).

Rather than printing out just the exception's *message*, you should log the whole exception, including the stack trace. That will let you find out exactly which line in the program is causing a problem, so you can fix it by checking for nullity first.

Note that [`DBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx) is not the same as a `null` value either as a `null` reference or a nullable value type's default value.

Comment: How may i do that is there anything you could advise of doing this?

Comment: @AsanSmith: Do what, exactly? Log the full exception? Check for nullity? It's hard to help you with the nullity check as we don't know where it's going wrong or what your code looks like (e.g. whether you're using a DataTable, a DataReader etc.)

Comment: @AsanSmith First off, look at the exception's stack trace, or better yet, step through the program in a debugger to identify where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: It errors on the line that says ItemDefinitionManager.Initialize(client);

Comment: Ive recently added a colum called energy_type that is to do with ItemDefinition , energy_type varchar 31

Comment: @AsanSmith: I'm sure it's somewhere *within* the `Initialize` method then, but we don't know what that looks like. We haven't seen any of your code.